# PowerApps TimeUnit.XXX no longer recognized since Update?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-component-framework

Everything was working fine until the update of components 1-2 days ago. Without any change to my specific code block. TimeUnit.anything is no longer recognized. I can still use e.g. TimeUnit.Hours in the canvas app area, the problem only occures in the components tab.

Why does this error occur? TimeUnit.XXX is a built in function...

In my PowerApps app, I have a component with the "function" getTextFromTimeRounded, shown in this image:

[image: properties of getTextFromTimeRounded]

My code:

```
If(
    IsBlankOrError(timeValue);
    "";
    DateDiff(Now(); timeValue; TimeUnit.Hours) >= 24;
    $"ca. {Round(DateDiff(Now(); timeValue; TimeUnit.Hours) / 24; 0)} Tag(en)";
    DateDiff(Now(); timeValue; TimeUnit.Minutes) >= 60; 
    $"ca. {Round(DateDiff(Now(); timeValue; TimeUnit.Minutes) / 60; 0)} h";
    $"{DateDiff(Now(); timeValue; TimeUnit.Minutes)} min"
)
```

Every `TimeUnit.XXX` is marked as an error, "TimeUnit.Hours is not recognized", but it works fine in the canvas.

[image: Code Block with TimeUnit marked as error]

Comment: UPDATE: The error is still there.... but somehow it works now.. i don't know whats going on... the error is there but it's also not there...

Comment: There is currently a known issue with accessing enumeration values (such as TimeUnit.*) inside components; this is being fixed by the Power Apps team, and I believe the fix should be completed today.

Comment: This should have been fixed already, please let me know if you still see this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as carlosfigueira mentioned, this issue has been fixed